# Where should I place namespace declarations

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two choices.

The one is to declare namespaces into the root tag of the XSL.
For example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0">
    <xsl:template name="root" match="/">
        <xsl:element name="fo:content">
            <xsl:value-of select="'alabala'"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The other one is to use `namespace` attribute into `<xsl:element>` or `<xsl:attribute/>`. Here is the second example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template name="root" match="/">
        <xsl:element name="fo:content" namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0">
            <xsl:value-of select="'alabala'"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which one approach is more appropriate? Is there any difference between both?

Comment: The difference? Try to use fo:content outside xsl:element! More appropriate? Honestly I find first one _easier_ but it's a matter of preferences (AFAIK)...

Comment: The difference is that a namespace declared in the opening tag of the stylesheet (or any other element) becomes in-scope for all descendants of that element and does not need to be declared again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, XSLT allows you to write literal result elements so you don't need to use `xsl:element` at all unless you want to compute the element name and/or namespace at run-time.

So use

```
<fo:content>...</fo:content>
```

respectively

```
<fo:content  xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0">...</fo:content>
```

As for the namespace, well, if you want to create child and descendant elements of `fo:content` only in the sample template, then the namespace declarations on the single elements suffices.

If you want to create elements in that namespace in other templates, then you need to declare it in those templates as well or move it up to the `xsl:stylesheet` as a convenient, single declaration.